# what does this type of statement mean var heli:graphic = new graphic();

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, variables

```
var heli:graphic = new graphic();
```

I was searching on why addChild not knows what is the graphic and then i found this 
actually it was

```
var heli:helicopter = new helicopter();
```

I dont understand why cant we write only this

```
var heli:helicopter
```

so we can also say i can not make sense of the statement

```
var one:Number = 3
```

I understand this one ^ we have a variable , type and value but on the other heli statement i am confused with what thing it is (i fully understand var in it but nothing else in it)

I am new in coding so please try to explain me as much as you can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing `var one:Number = 3` equals writing `var one:Number = new Number(3);`

What you're actually doing is defining a variable, that needs to be of type Number and assigning to it an object. Number, as any other primitive (ie. String), can be shortened to a form of `3`.

The `new helicopter()` bit - you're creating an object of type `helicopter`, by utilizing constructor function - `()`.

You can write `var heli:helicopter`, but then the variable won't be initialized. It will have an undefined value, and the only thing the compiler will know, is that it needs be of type `helicopter`.